# After upgrade to 20.04 "Use this connection only for resources on its network" doesn't work

Tags: vpn, l2tp

I have upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 on my laptop. I have had two VPN connections to my office, one that route all traffic through the VPN and one that only route traffic to my office network through the VPN. I accomplished this by checking the "Use this connection only for its network" and adding a manual route in Network manager for the VPN that should only be used for the office network.
After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 the latter VPN doesn't work. If I uncheck "Use this connection only for its network" the VPN works, but when checking it I cannot access anything. When connected to the VPN with the "Use this connection only for its network" checked I cannot run the "route" command, it simply hangs. The VPNs are L2TP.

Answer (score 0):

The `route` command is probably trying to do reverse DNS lookups and waiting for timeout. Try with `route -n` option to suppress that.